# Is there any way I can be sure a wall is NOT load bearing?

Tags: building-design

I've Googled the hell out of this and it doesn't seem to be, i.e.

- It's structured like a standard stud (not reinforced top)
- It doesn't run along a floor joist
- The uprights are pretty badly cut and not snug

But it looks to me like the remains of an attic support structure (it an attic conversion/extension into a dormer-like structure) and to my untrained eye, it seems like a lot of roof (80" from nearest edge to back wall) to support itself.

I was planning on building a stud wall on the outside edge and running a support beam along the length to be safe but is there any way I can be sure that the support isn't even needed?

[image: Wall I want rid of]

Comment: Not to sound sarcastic, but the best way to be sure is to bring in a licenced architect or home inspector.

Comment: I could spend a few hundred pounds on that, or I could take the opportunity to learn something

Comment: But Ross, unless you learn exactly what the expert knows (which you won't get from answers here),  your project is at risk.

Comment: Please give us some feedback if your roof crashed after you took it out. :-) Thanks.

Comment: Update:  Nothing fell down when it was removed.  It's been gone for months now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That wall has not been designed to be load bearing by a structural engineer. As you say, it only has a single header (top beam) rather than a double, and the verticals aren't cut accurately enough.

What worries me... is that you say this was an attic conversion. Attic conversions are sometimes done by people who don't understand what they're doing and don't follow structural regulations.

So as long as you're happy that the conversion was done properly, you're completely safe to take out that stud wall.

---

> to my untrained eye, it seems like a lot of roof (80" from nearest edge to back wall) to support itself.

Roof tiles sit on purlins (small horizontal timbers) that sit on rafters (the big diagonal members that basically define the shape of the roof). In a normal roof you have a truss, which supports the rafters. However, it is completely possible to design rafters such that there is just a triangle (left inclined rafter, right inclined rafter, and a ceiling/floor joist joining them). It's just that you'll need bigger rafters, and better joints, then if you have a truss.

This is why I worry about attic conversions: if someone just cuts out the inner truss without redesigning the rafters, you can get understrength roofs. And a non-load bearing wall might be mitigating that, until it's removed.

Comment: Was it that builder from "Fawlty Towers" ? :)

Comment: @SolarMike - Having read the synopsis on Wikipedia, yes! (Amazing that I don't remember that episode, considering there are only 12 of them to remember!)

Comment: these bad attic conversion you speak of.  Does that apply to taking a sloped roof cutting out a square and effectively attaching a square block?

Comment: @RossDrew - I'm not 100% sure I understand what you're saying. I *think* you're talking about adding a [dormer window](https://www.google.co.uk/search?biw=766&bih=732&tbm=isch&sa=1&ei=VGpoWtD7HYWvgAbWuKaYBA&q=dormer+loft+conversion&oq=dormer+loft&gs_l=psy-ab.1.0.0l10.4453.4987.0.6038.4.3.0.1.1.0.48.131.3.3.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.4.134....0.1R0wVse9nzI)? They can be done safely in a structurally sound way, or they can be done badly, just like anything else.

Comment: @RossDrew - That said, I was more talking about taking a King Post truss and turning it into e.g. an Attic truss, without actually checking to see if the rafters are strong enough for it. [Truss types](http://sans10400.co.za/wp-content/uploads/2011/11/TrussTypes1-s.jpg)

Comment: @AndyT I Googled dormer window and yes, it's kinda like that.

Comment: @AndyT So I'll go with my safety plan of building the new wall, running a support from it, along and against the angled roof to the far wall then a couple supports along the bottom where I'll be building [some drawers](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/6654/are-there-any-non-obvious-specifically-structural-concerns-to-building-a-walk).
That should be plenty support, right?

Comment: @RossDrew - Honestly I'm not really sure what you're proposing; I find it difficult to build a 3d picture from words. But you shouldn't need any support at all (assuming the original conversion was done right) so anything you do put in should be plenty. I have no idea on statistics of how frequently attic conversions are done wrong, but I suspect it's pretty low.

Comment: @AndyT essentially just a support beam across the legth of the angled roof supported on each side.  Thanks :D

Answer (score 2):

I have seen many of these DIY jobs by home owners that has been defying any sense of logic. Not only this could be a part of support of the roof by cutting the diagonal 2x4s that supported the rafters. It may not be even sitting on a solid member of framing.

I would try to get a read of the framing both of roof and floor of attic.

An experienced Carpenter could help.

I have a small probe that can send it's camera through a 1/4 inch hole and has a few LED lights to light up dark places. This probe connects to your droid phone and you can record what you see. I bought it for $28 from Amazon, it is really a handy tool.

Comment: Already have one of those but I have the luxury and will to just pull up (or away) anything I want to see behind.

Comment: ... it seems to be sitting on the fibreboard, just above the space between two floor joists.

Comment: @RossDrew , yes your job now is to verify the possible damage the guy who did this has done? Did he remove something he shouldn't have? Has he compromised the strength of roof or ceiling below?

Answer (score 1):

Is that stud mounted onto the plasterboard? If so, it is not supporting.

If the plasterboard buts up to the stud then it is supporting, but I don’t think it is - it looks to be added to make a « cupboard » or just hide stuff.

Comment: It is on the plasterboard, yes.